# How to use filter query in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I have the below document in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "64db631f0d0fdd7ca171925"
    },
    "Score": {
        "tpp": [{
                "Created": "2023-08-15T11:35:59.981703",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "tpp_test_23-08-15",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 98.82101328853868,
                        "S2": 0.4462460709111595,
                        "S3": 0.9903934442528318
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Created": "2023-08-16T04:58:42.938363",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "tpp_test_23-08-16",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 89.55948960968257,
                        "S2": 0.4225249957393492,
                        "S3": 0.9406028378220205
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Created": "2023-08-21T06:51:20.019846",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "tpp_test_23-08-21",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 6005.298012684006,
                        "S2": 18.240124141272748,
                        "S3": 0.7677129826854888
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "jpp": [{
                "Created": "2023-08-15T11:36:01.029291",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "jpp_test_23-08-15",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 137.16463053637148,
                        "S2": 5.72343800247094,
                        "S3": 0.7272226687010683
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Created": "2023-08-16T04:58:43.961270",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "jpp_test_23-08-16",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 105.42995098464753,
                        "S2": 4.771941948328004,
                        "S3": 0.7455133155913495
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Created": "2023-08-21T06:51:34.957546",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "jpp_test_23-08-21",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 188.51286984081415,
                        "S2": 9.144808573503445,
                        "S3": 0.7075201622161631
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "kpp": [{
                "Created": "2023-08-15T11:36:10.937782",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "kpp_test_23-08-15",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 1636631594963893200,
                        "S2": 917076193.5423952,
                        "S3": 0.9417499348965086
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Created": "2023-08-16T04:58:52.831913",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "kpp_test_23-08-16",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 3217780416598932500,
                        "S2": 1275510295.2016292,
                        "S3": 0.8844345905437582
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Created": "2023-08-18T18:37:23.488407",
                "Data": {
                    "Name": "kpp_test_23-08-18",
                    "Scores": {
                        "S1": 64290310924.15908,
                        "S2": 156601.431911856,
                        "S3": 0.7523852737957368
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using the filter query tab in Compass

[image]

So I have lot of other documents in the db and when I run this filter query, it shows the above document. What I am trying to do is to just show the below dict only:

```
{
    "Created": "2023-08-15T11:35:59.981703",
    "Data": {
        "Name": "tpp_test_23-08-15",
        "Scores": {
            "S1": 98.82101328853868,
            "S2": 0.4462460709111595,
            "S3": 0.9903934442528318
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done in a simple query.

Instead, you should look for an aggregation pipeline.

1. `$match` - Filter documents.
2. `$project` - Decorate the output document with the `tpp` field which is an array containing the matching element(s) of `Scores.tpp`.
3. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `tpp` array into multiple documents.
4. `$replaceWith` - Replace input document with `tpp` (document) value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "Score.tpp.Data.Scores.S3": 0.9903934442528318
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tpp: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Score.tpp",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.Data.Scores.S3",
              0.9903934442528318
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tpp"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$tpp"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w9jfpRgiH3Q)